# CCTV integration to my page in angular2

Tags: angular

Can any one help me how to intergrate the cctv to my angular2 webapp. I have the ip and port as input based on that i need to show it in my page . Can anyone worked on it or any idea please help me on this. With any sample example. Mine is a angular-cli webapplication.

Comment: you need to show Live CCTV Footage ?

Comment: both live and recorded I has to make to view

Comment: did u tried HTML5 Video Tag ?..

Comment: No yet tried , I am thinking in angular2 perspective.

Comment: whats there in angular 2 ? you will be displaying it in HTML only so what you wanna do with angular 2

Comment: I tried by using source and video tag of html its works fine. TY

Comment: Ohh Okay Sounds Good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML code

```
<button type="button" class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-info': item.status>0, 'btn-default': item.status==0}" (click)="openCCTV(url)">VIEW</button>
```

ts code

```
public openCCTV(urlToOpen: string) {
    let url: string = '';
    if (!/^http[s]?:\/\//.test(urlToOpen)) {
       url += 'http://';
    }

    url += urlToOpen;
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  };
```